# MSBuild System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex not matching

Tags: regex, msbuild

I am trying to **extract the final digit** from a string like `1.2.3` using a regular expression, and cant seem to do it.

I thought that using `\d$` would be sufficient, but it does not work when using regular expressions in the following MSBuild file:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.5.0</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="TestXmlPeek">
        <XmlPeek 
            Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='msb' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;" 
            XmlInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" 
            Query="/msb:Project/msb:PropertyGroup/msb:AssemblyVersion/text()">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
        </XmlPeek>

        <Message Text="@(Peeked)"/>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(Peeked), `\d$`))</Out>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Message Text="Input: [@(Peeked)] Output: [$(Out)]"/>
    </Target>   
</Project>
```

When I run the TestXmlPeek target I see the following output:

```
TestXmlPeek:
  1.5.0   
  Input: [1.5.0] Output: []
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

(BTW: I am doing this as I'd like to use an MSBuild target to eventually increment my version numbers.)

**Edit**

I am pretty sure that MSBuild and regex is working, as if I use the following simply expression, I do see it match the entire string and printing out `1.5.0`.

```
<Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(Peeked), `.*`))</Out>
```

Comment: Did you try changing `\`\d$\`` with `"\d$"`?

Comment: I've tried replacing the ` with " but it has made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `@(Peeked)` is somehow not simply transformed into the string containing the characters `1.5.0` when passed to a property function. I admit I didn't check what it actually does instead, but that doesn't mean the fix doesn't work :] Turn it into a string first:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="TestXmlPeek">
<ItemGroup>
    <Peeked Include="1.5.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="TestXmlPeek">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <JustText>@(Peeked)</JustText>
        <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(JustText), "\d$"))</Out>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Match: $(Out)"/>
</Target>   
</Project>
```

(I used `""` here but ``` `` ``` works just as well)

Answer (score 0):

Use \\d$ rather than \d$ - you want a literal \ in the regex, and in a C# string you need to use \\ to get that.

Comment: I'm not sure how many \ you intended me to use, as it looks like SO may have removed some when displaying your answer. So I have tried the following combinations without luck: `\d$`, `\\d$`, `\\\d$` and `\\\\d$`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a line break at the end of the string, have a try with:

```
\.(\d+)[\r\n]*$
```

This will capture, in group 1, the lasts digits after a dot and before eventual line break.

Comment: Thank you, but no luck. You can actually see from the output that there is no line break as `[1.5.0]` gets printed, so I don't think there is a line break. I think the problem is not in the actual regex, but in how it is getting interpreted by the engine?